# How to fill missing values in a dataframe depending on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

I want to replace null values with `df[col].mean()` when `df[col]` is not all null values.

I implement code like below:

```py
if train_x[cols].isna().sum() == len(train_x): # need to fix
    train_x.loc[:, cols] = train_x[cols].fillna(value=0.0)
else:
    train_x.loc[:, cols] = train_x[cols].fillna(value=train_x[cols].mean())
```

This code has error, because `train_x[cols]`  is a dataframe, but I need to put each column under condition.

Is there a better way to implement my purpose?

Sorry for my poor English skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col1": [1, 9, pd.NA], "col2": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA], "col3": [8, 4, 3]}
)

print(df)
# Output
   col1  col2  col3
0     1  <NA>     8
1     9  <NA>     4
2  <NA>  <NA>     3
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].isna().sum() == df.shape[0]:
        df[col] = 0
    else:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].mean())
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0     0     8
1   9.0     0     4
2   5.0     0     3
```